# A regex to match string that doesnt start with ... and doesnt end with

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I'm trying to find a Regex that matches a word but doesn't start/end with a specific character.

Example:
The Search word is mini

it should match:

```
mini
mini abc
mini-abc (- could be anything else but not [a-zA-Z0-9])
abc mini
abc-mini (- could be anything else but [a-zA-Z0-9])
abc mini abc
abcminiabc-mini (- could be anything else but not [a-zA-Z0-9])
mini-abcminiabc (- could be anything else but not [a-zA-Z0-9])
miniabc-mini (- could be anything else but not [a-zA-Z0-9])
mini-miniabc (- could be anything else but not [a-zA-Z0-9])
abcmin-mini (- could be anything else but not [a-zA-Z0-9])
mini-abcmini (- could be anything else but not [a-zA-Z0-9])
```

but not:

```
miniabc
abcmini
abcminiabc
miniabc abc
abc abcmini
abcminiabc abc
abc abcminiabc
```

I've tried something like this:

```
^(.*)([^a-zA-Z0-9]{0,1})MINI([^a-zA-Z0-9]{0,1})(.*)$
```

But that doesn't seems to work since this also matches 'miniabc', 'abcmini', 'abcminiabc', which isn't what i wanted.

(Language is PHP in case it isn't possible in MySQL.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use lookaround based regex in PHP (PCRE):

```
(?<![a-zA-Z0-9])mini(?![a-zA-Z0-9])
```

- `(?![a-zA-Z0-9])` is *negative lookahead* that asserts that next position doesn't have `[a-zA-Z0-9]` characters
- `(?<![a-zA-Z0-9])` is *negative lookbehind* that asserts that previous position doesn't have `[a-zA-Z0-9]` characters

[More on lookarounds regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eA2fY6/3)

Comment: Works perfect. Thank you.

Also the answer from splash with the boundaries was nice but underscore (mini_) wouldn't match.

In case anyone else have the same problem and doesn't care about underscore `[[:<:]]mini[[:>:]]` could be done in mysql.